# Matlab error with loading and plotting matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have saved a matrix as A76.mat file. I am trying to load it and plot its graph:

```
A=load('A76.mat')
G = graph(A,'upper');
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error using matlab.internal.graph.constructFromEdgeList (line 189)
Node IDs must both be numeric vectors, both be node names (specified as string 
vectors, character vectors, or cell arrays of
character vectors), or both be categoricals.

Error in graph (line 300)
            matlab.internal.graph.constructFromEdgeList(...

Error in lti_76 (line 14)
G = graph(A,'upper');
```

If I don't attribute the loading of A76 to A, then Matlab proceeds to the normal computations without me having specified what A is equal to. And frankly there is no other A matrix saved that would interfere with the code and would read that instead of the one i want.

```
load('A76.mat')
G = graph(A,'upper');
```

Could someone help me with why this happens?

Comment: when you `load` to a variable, it create a struct. In your first example, I assume `graph(A.A,'upper')` works

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the documentation for any function that behaves differently than you expect. MATLAB has really good documentation. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html

Comment: Note that a MAT-file can contain many variables, it doesn’t just store one matrix.